# SignInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync() выдаёт NullReference

Tags: c#, исключения, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь вызвать `signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user)`, а он чудит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жалуется на NullReference, но где именно? Параметр не null и это видно на скрине.

Полный стректрейс:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.GetClaimsAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user)
   at NameThatTitle.WebApp.Controllers.AccountController.GetIdentity(String login, String password) in C:\Users\kamil\source\repos\NameThatTitle\src\NameThatTitle.WebApp\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 129
```

Comment: Выглядит так как будто контекст задиспозили...

Comment: @PavelMayorov всмысле? Судя по дебагу, аргумент имеет значение перед вызовом метода. А дальше внутри метода моего вмешательства быть не может =/

Comment: Какой аргумент? Я про контекст говорю.

Comment: @PavelMayorov HttpContext?

Comment: IdentityDbContext, блин!

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как он смог то прямо в рантайме? До этого он нормально добавил нового пользователя в БД с помощью `userManager.CreateAsync()`

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил пользователя, потом пытался создать токен для него, а перед этим получить `ClaimPrincipal`

Comment: Не знаю, ищите...

Comment: Используете где-нибудь `ConcurrencyStamp` или атрибут `ConcurrencyCheck`, или `IsConcurrencyToken()`?

Comment: @Groxan, нет. вот контроллер целиком - https://pastebin.com/m66Z1evp

Comment: проблема исчезла, оказывается я забыл добавить `await` перед вызовом асинхронного метода (73 строчка)